# Access Value from an associative table in a Vuex store to Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, associative-array

I have a store in Vuex that store some values in an associative array.
When I get this values in Vuejs,I don't know how to display them.

These are the value that I get from console.log:

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
  0:
   __ob__: Observer
    dep: Dep
     id: 88
   subs: [Watcher]
  __proto__: Object
  value: {__ob__: Observer}
  vmCount: 0
  __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
  __proto__: Array
```

I try to access the values of this array but when I do :

```
for(let index in searchValues[0]) {
  ...
  console.log("help")
}
```

It doesn't show anything

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is your `Vuex` Store?

Comment: Please edit your question with Vuex code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to get 'id' from the object observer

Try to use

```
let { id } = searchValues[0];
```

Instead of

```
let id = searchValues[0].id;
```